# Error Message when trying to scrape FBref webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Disclaimer: I am still a python beginner and trying to scrape for the first time.

I am trying to scrape player stats from the current (22/23) Champions League season and convert it to a .csv file. If you see any other obvious errors then please point it out.

Website: https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/stats/Champions-League-Stats

I tried to change the following code to get it working for my needs but I am not successful:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PoHtZWcy8WaU1hnWmL7eCVUbxzci3-fr#scrollTo=2qYGN7pfk3gK

There is the possibility to simply directly download a .csv file but I need to actually scrape the webpage.

This is my (modified from above) code and I get the following error message and don't know how to resolve the problem:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re


# Functions to get the data in a dataframe using BeautifulSoup

def get_tables(url, text):
    res = requests.get(url)
    ## The next two lines get around the issue with comments breaking the parsing.
    comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comm.sub("", res.text), 'lxml')
    all_tables = soup.findAll("table")

    player_table = all_tables[2]
    if text == 'for':
        return player_table
    if text != 'for':
        pass


def get_frame(features, player_table):
    pre_df_player = dict()
    features_wanted_player = features
    rows_player = player_table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows_player:
        if (row.find('th', {"scope": "row"}) is not None):

            for f in features_wanted_player:
                cell = row.find("td", {"data-stat": f})
                a = cell.data.text().encode()
                text = a.decode("utf-8")
                if (text == ''):
                    text = '0'
                if ((f != 'player') & (f != 'nationality') & (f != 'position') & (f != 'squad') & (f != 'age') & (
                        f != 'birth_year')):
                    text = float(text.replace(',', ''))
                if f in pre_df_player:
                    pre_df_player[f].append(text)
                else:
                    pre_df_player[f] = [text]
    df_player = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pre_df_player)
    return df_player


def frame_for_category(category, top, end, features):
    url = (top + category + end)
    player_table = get_tables(url, 'for')
    df_player = get_frame(features, player_table)
    return df_player


# Function to get the player data for outfield player, includes all categories - standard stats, shooting
# passing, passing types, goal and shot creation, defensive actions, possession, and miscallaneous
def get_outfield_data(top, end):
    df1 = frame_for_category('stats', top, end, stats)
    df2 = frame_for_category('shooting', top, end, shooting2)
    df3 = frame_for_category('passing', top, end, passing2)
    df4 = frame_for_category('passing_types', top, end, passing_types2)
    df5 = frame_for_category('gca', top, end, gca2)
    df6 = frame_for_category('defense', top, end, defense2)
    df7 = frame_for_category('possession', top, end, possession2)
    df8 = frame_for_category('misc', top, end, misc2)
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8], axis=1)
    df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
    return df


# Function to get keeping and advance goalkeeping data
def get_keeper_data(top, end):
    df1 = frame_for_category('keepers', top, end, keepers)
    df2 = frame_for_category('keepersadv', top, end, keepersadv2)
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
    return df

#This cell is to get the outfield player data for any competition

#Go to the 'Standard stats' page of the league
#For Champions League 2022/23, the link is this: https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/stats/Champions-League-Stats
#Remove the 'stats', and pass the first and third part of the link as parameters like below
df_outfield = get_outfield_data('https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/','/Champions-League-Stats')

#Save csv file to Desktop
df_outfield.to_csv('CL2022_23_Outfield.csv',index=False)

df_outfield
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/student/Pycharm/Scraping FBREF.py", line 123, in <module>
    df_outfield = get_outfield_data('https://fbref.com/en/comps/8/','/Champions-League-Stats')
  File "/home/student/Pycharm/Scraping FBREF.py", line 97, in get_outfield_data
    df1 = frame_for_category('stats', top, end, stats)
  File "/home/student/Pycharm/Scraping FBREF.py", line 90, in frame_for_category
    df_player = get_frame(features, player_table)
  File "/home/student/Pycharm/Scraping FBREF.py", line 72, in get_frame
    a = cell.data.text().encode()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: `cell.data` is `None`.  you need to check for that condition before trying to access the `.text` attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: @JohnGordon It says that there is a beautifulsoup tag element but I seem to be unable to get to the data. I would really appreciate further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. I had to add an if-statement to only encode when the cell is not None:

```
            for f in features_wanted_player:
            cell = row.find("td", {"data-stat": f})
            if cell is not None:
                a = cell.text.strip().encode()
```

Now it works perfectly fine.